# How to loop and get data from xml converted to json?

Tags: jquery, json, xml

I have converted xml into json and want to get some data using looping process. Actually, I want to get data in term of title,description and link,but I'm stacked here and giving error.

```
$(function(){
      url = 'http://www.straitstimes.com/news/sport/rss.xml';
      $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1000&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
      dataType: 'json',
      error: function(){
          alert('Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed');
      },
      success: function(xml){

        html='';
              console.log(xml.responseData.feed.entries); 

              for (var i = 0; i < xml.responseData.feed.entries .length; i++){
               html+=  xml.responseData.feed.entries[i].title+'<br/>'+
               html+=  xml.responseData.feed.entries[i].description+'<br/>'+
               html+=  xml.responseData.feed.entries[i].link+'<br/>';
           }
           $('#feedContainer').html(html);

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you post the error also?

Comment: I got "ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side"

Comment: There's a space between entries and ".length" in your for loop, for starters.

Comment: Oh,still same error even remove space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct code [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dvcypmx/1/)

Some issues with your syntax on the html += lines. (The + were incorrect).

I separated out the url declarations for myself (just to make sure there was no issues).

```
 $(function(){
   var url1 = 'http://www.straitstimes.com/news/sport/rss.xml';
   var url2 = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1000&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url1);
  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url:  url2,
  dataType: 'json',
  error: function(){
      alert('Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed');
  },
  success: function(xml){

    html='';
          console.log(xml.responseData.feed.entries); 

          for (var i = 0; i < xml.responseData.feed.entries.length; i++) {
              console.log(xml.responseData.feed.entries[i].title);
          html +=  xml.responseData.feed.entries[i].title+'<br/>';
          html +=  xml.responseData.feed.entries[i].description+'<br/>';
          html +=  xml.responseData.feed.entries[i].link+'<br/>';
       }
       $('#feedContainer').html(html);

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Oh,thank oliromahony, I did not notice that,It working,but description is undefined output,can help me for this issue?

Comment: np, http://jsfiddle.net/6dvcypmx/3/ you are looking at the wrong property name - it should be content like in that fiddle

Comment: Oh,ok,that is working fine now,thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 2):

When you use the += constructor, you're adding to an already defined variable. You therefore do not need the + at the end of the line, you need to end the statement. So

```
 html+=  xml.responseData.feed.entries[i].title+'<br/>'+
 html+=  xml.responseData.feed.entries[i].description+'<br/>'+
 html+=  xml.responseData.feed.entries[i].link+'<br/>';
```

should be either

```
html+=  xml.responseData.feed.entries[i].title+'<br/>';
html+=  xml.responseData.feed.entries[i].description+'<br/>;
html+=  xml.responseData.feed.entries[i].link+'<br/>';
```

or

```
 html =  xml.responseData.feed.entries[i].title+'<br/>'+
 xml.responseData.feed.entries[i].description+'<br/>'+
 xml.responseData.feed.entries[i].link+'<br/>';
```

Comment: hehe,ok,I did not notice them :)